# AOC I1659FWUX USB-Powered Portable monitor stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, usb, multiple-monitors

Everything was perfect, out of the box working as a third monitor then one day it stops working.  I plug it into my USB 3.0 Hub which I was doing before and get the AOC logo then a black screen and it is not identified in Settings.

Took it in for warranty repairs but they only check on Windows.

Comment: Does it work when you plug it directly into your computer?

Comment: I'll try this later but that involves disconnecting my external hard drive off of which I run Ubuntu because I have a limited number of USB ports.

Comment: @Nmath no, it does not work and I tried installing the DisplayLink Driver as well