# Problems installing DisplayLink Driver on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

````
```
nobu@nobu-IdeaPad-3-15IIL05:/media/nobu/NTFSUbuWin/downloadsUbu/DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu5.5-EXE$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.5.0-59.151.run
[sudo] password for nobu: 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   MD5 checksums are OK. All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.5.0-59.151  100%  
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Installing
[ Installing EVDI ]
[[ Installing EVDI DKMS module ]]

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/source ->
                 /usr/src/evdi-1.10.1

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=5.13.0-40-generic all INCLUDEDIR=/lib/modules/5.13.0-40-generic/build/include KVERSION=5.13.0-40-generic DKMS_BUILD=1....(bad exit status: 2)
sh: 0: getcwd() failed: No such file or directory
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for evdi: 1.10.1 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/evdi/1.10.1/build/make.log for more information.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 1.10.1
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
ERROR: Failed to install evdi to the kernel tree.
```
````

I need this for my AOC usb monitor for which I asked: [AOC I1659FWUX USB-Powered Portable monitor stopped working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1400920/aoc-i1659fwux-usb-powered-portable-monitor-stopped-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)

I tried Googling the error but the conversation was getting too difficult for me to follow.

Comment: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0 <- Please check the "warning", make sure you have the dependencies installed and try again. Also make sure you system is fully updated.

Comment: @ChanganAuto it worked!  I followed those directions after downloading and unzipping `'DisplayLink USB Graphics Software for Ubuntu5.5-EXE.zip'
`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the OP was: follow these instructions: [How to install DisplayLink software on Ubuntu 20.04](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0). See their comments under the question.

If anyone else is struggling in general with the install, see my new answer here: [Full instructions: installing displaylink-driver on Ubuntu 20.04 (also applies to 22.04 or later)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1488249/327339)